# Using external storage for Vert.x Session Management

Tags: java, session, redis, vert.x

Vert.x inbuilt session store LocalSessionStore and ClusteredSessionStoreImpl use local Maps to store session. If I use Redis or any data store for session management i cannot directly serialize them as they don't have properly defined getters and setter. Furthermore, SessionImpl has id as private field with no setters. So even if i have proxy class i cannot re create Session.

How do i store sessions externally then ?

Answer (score 1):

SessionImpl implements the ClusterSerializable interface, which gives you 2 methods - writeToBuffer and readFromBuffer.
You can use them to serialize / deserialize to external stores like redis.

Comment: I think the proper approach is to implement SessionStore since the redis requests need to be async. writeToBuffer and readFromBuffer are synchronous since they don't provide a callback and you also don't have the information available to make good decisions at that low level.